# how can I retrieve data from firebase to a table view controller and pass it to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I retrieved my data using firebase database into a table view cell in a view controller. I want to forward the data to another view controller.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKm2T.png) i try by creating variables assigning them to table view cells label but when trying to retrieve the app crashed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T6hb.png). here are my sample codes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKm2T.png)

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZKBK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and add your code not as a picture.

Comment: Please do not post your code as images. Use plain text

Answer (score 0):

This function expects an `Any` as parameter, so in your function `didSelectRowAt` you can get the object using the index `atIndexPath` getting the object from the array you used to populate the `tableView` and send this object in the `sender` parameter:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)
```

You should then implement this function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

There you can retrieve your object in the `sender` and the view controller in the property `segue.destination` which is a `UIViewController` so you can convert it to your ViewController and pass the object to the next one.